# Error While sending mails using Java Mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am getting the following error while sending mails using Java Mail.
Below is the error. Could you please let me know the causes on the error.

```
ERROR :: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.SendFailedException: 452 Too many recipients received this hour
```

## Below is the method causing Exception.

public void sendTextReport(DataBean dataBean, TextBean textBean) throws IOException, MessagingException {

```
    Session session = getAuthentication();


        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.props.getProperty("from")));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(this.props.getProperty("textTo")));
        message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,InternetAddress.parse(this.props.getProperty("textCc")));

        message.setSubject(" Report for the submissions between "+ dates.getDate1() + " and " + dates.getDate2());

        StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();

        mailBody.append("<text>Hi All,<br><br>Below is the Report for the submissions </text><br><br><br>");
        mailBody.append("<table><tr><th>Description</th><th>Count</th></tr>");

        LinkedHashMap map=(LinkedHashMap) getTextMap(dataBean,textBean);
        Iterator it=map.entrySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Entry<String, Integer> entry=(Entry) it.next();
            mailBody.append("<tr><td>"+entry.getKey()+"</th><td class='count'>"+entry.getValue()+"</td></tr>");
        } 


        BodyPart messageBodyPart1 = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart1.setContent(mailBody.toString(), "text/html");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart1);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        Transport.send(message);
```

## }

```
public Session getAuthentication() {

    final String host = this.props.getProperty("from");
    final String password = this.props.getProperty("password");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", this.props.getProperty("hostName"));
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,null);
    return session;
```

## }

textTo: This string contains 3 email addresses
textCc: this String contains 1 Distribution list which has 8 email addresses.

All are valid email addresses. I checked with getValidUnsentAddresses() in SendFailedException.Seems all are valid but not sent.

Answer (score 1):

This is called grey-listing. When you send too many e-mails (or more often - a certain number of e-mails where a recipient does not exist) a destination mail server does not black list you, but instead they temporarily block access from your mail server (essentially the IP address of your mail server). Usually this block is set for 1 hour but obviously can vary depending on the configuration.

You can do several things:

1.Contact the admins of the domain in question (e.g. postmaster@messaging.sprintpcs.com) and request your IP address to be whitelisted. (They may refuse).

2.Check/increase time e-mails can stay in your local queues (to have more chances of them to retry and finally get delivered.

3.Add more public IP addresses to your server

Comment: This question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338182/sendmail-error-452-too-many-recipients-received-this-hour

Comment: thanks for the reply.. But,my code is not sending too many mails, hardly it contains 20 recepients and all are  valid email addresses..

Comment: I have added the code  above.. In Question.. Please have a look and let me know if more info required.