# Sending Multiple mail using java mail API is giving error

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

We have written method to send mail using java mail API. Our mail server is behind the proxy server.

We are able to send 3 to 4 mail continuously successfully, but the exception occurs when we send we sent 100 or more mail, could please guide me in this regards

```
public static void sendHtmlEmail(PropertiesSerDto dto, String to, String subject, String message) throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", dto.getEmailHost());
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", dto.getEmailPort());
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

        final String user = dto.getEmailUser();
        final String password = dto.getEmailPassword();
        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message messageContent = new MimeMessage(session);
        messageContent.setFrom(new InternetAddress(dto.getEmailFrom()));

        InternetAddress[] iAdressArray = InternetAddress.parse(to);
        messageContent.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, iAdressArray);
        messageContent.setSubject(subject);
        messageContent.setSentDate(new Date());
        // set plain text message
        messageContent.setContent(message, "text/html");
        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(messageContent);

    }


Error com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 450 4.7.1 Error: too much mail from 172.16.3.182

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1515)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at com.mycomp.util.MailUtil.sendHtmlEmail(MailUtil.java:54)
at com.mycomp.asn.bean.AsnBean.sendMailToSourcing(AsnBean.java:325)
at com.mycomp.asn.bean.AsnBean.createAsn(AsnBean.java:174)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.RequestInvocationContext.proceedFinal(RequestInvocationContext.java:47)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:166)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_StatesTransition.invoke(Interceptors_StatesTransition.java:19)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Resource.invoke(Interceptors_Resource.java:50)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Transaction.doWorkWithAttribute(Interceptors_Transaction.java:37)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_Transaction.invoke(Interceptors_Transaction.java:21)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_MethodRetry.invoke(Interceptors_MethodRetry.java:46)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:191)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_StatelessInstanceGetter.invoke(Interceptors_StatelessInstanceGetter.java:23)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_SecurityCheck.invoke(Interceptors_SecurityCheck.java:25)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.Interceptors_ExceptionTracer.invoke(Interceptors_ExceptionTracer.java:17)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.AbstractInvocationContext.proceed(AbstractInvocationContext.java:179)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultInvocationChainsManager.startChain(DefaultInvocationChainsManager.java:138)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.java:172)
at com.sap.engine.services.ejb3.runtime.impl.DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(DefaultEJBProxyInvocationHandler.java:99)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4289.createAsn(Unknown Source)
at com.mycomp.rest.AsnRest.createAsn(AsnRest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:152)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:38)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.runServlet(HttpHandlerImpl.java:466)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpHandlerImpl.java:210)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:441)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:430)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.DSRWebContainerFilter.process(DSRWebContainerFilter.java:38)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ServletSelector.process(ServletSelector.java:81)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ApplicationSelector.process(ApplicationSelector.java:278)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.WebContainerInvoker.process(WebContainerInvoker.java:81)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.ResponseLogWriter.process(ResponseLogWriter.java:60)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DefineHostFilter.process(DefineHostFilter.java:27)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MonitoringFilter.process(MonitoringFilter.java:29)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.SessionSizeFilter.process(SessionSizeFilter.java:26)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MemoryStatisticFilter.process(MemoryStatisticFilter.java:57)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DSRHttpFilter.process(DSRHttpFilter.java:43)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor.chainedRequest(Processor.java:475)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor$FCAProcessorThread.process(Processor.java:269)
at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.rcm.RequestProcessorThread.run(RequestProcessorThread.java:56)
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:122)
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:101)
at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:328)
```

Comment: The issue is not in the program. It's in the mail server. It is configured not to allow too many mails from a single address - it's a common measure against bulk mail (spam). If that mail server is under your control, you'll need to reconfigure it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check the limit with the mail server admins. There are limits imposed by mail servers via SMTP. For example Gmail's limit via SMTP is 100 total recipients per 24 hours.

> This is called grey-listing. When you send too many e-mails (or more
>   often - a certain number of e-mails where a recipient does not exist)
>   a destination mail server does not black list you, but instead they
>   temporarily block access from your mail server (essentially the IP
>   address of your mail server). Usually this block is set for 1 hour but
>   obviously can vary depending on the configuration.

[sendmail error 452 Too many recipients received this hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338182/sendmail-error-452-too-many-recipients-received-this-hour)